# Does the proximity effect in semiconductor/superconductor heterostructures require an accumulation layer

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, semiconductor-physics, superconductivity, mesoscopic-physics

I've recently been looking at literature on the proximity effect in semiconductor-superconductor heterostructures, where the semiconductor takes on superconductivity over mesoscopic distances. Examples of this are InAs-Al: [Hard gap in epitaxial semiconductor–superconductor nanowires](http://www.nature.com/articles/nnano.2014.306) by Chang et al. (2015) as well as InSb-Al: [Epitaxy of Advanced Nanowire Quantum Devices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01480) by Gazibegovic et al. (2017).

Now, what I was wondering is regarding the mechanism. In a crude sense, you need overlap between the SC and SM wavefunctions, causing them to hybridize. But how do you make sure you have overlap? One way of doing so is what I would think is the mechanism in InAs: it is known that InAs when contacted with Al leads to an accumulation layer at the surface, meaning an increased electron density close to the SC. There is thus essentially a well for electrons to sit in close to the interface, causing strong overlap between the two materials. This could explain the observation of a hard induced gap on the order of the aluminum gap itself.

For InSb-Al this is not so clear; InAs already has accumulation on its own without the Al, but InSb does not. That doesn't mean however that it won't when contacted with Al, and actually a crude work function/electron affinity comparison would suggest that it does have accumulation, but this is not known. However, in the opposite scenario I cannot envision having a hard induced gap on the order of the aluminum gap itself; if instead of accumulation there is depletion, the electrons will primarily live away from the SC interface, causing minimal overlap with the SC states. I don't see how this can then lead to such an induced gap.

My question is therefore as follows: does the proximity effect in semiconductor/superconductor heterostructures require an accumulation layer to form at the interface? I can believe that it might occur very weakly without, but in the form that is measured in these experiments, I can think of no other mechanism that'll allow for such a large induced gap. Most likely due to my lack of knowledge and imagination, but that is why I am asking.

As an edit, I stumbled upon the article [Induced superconductivity in high-mobility two-dimensional electron gas in gallium arsenide heterostructures](http://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms8426) by Wan et al (2015). Here they describe how they were able to induce superconductivity in GaAs only by strongly doping it, in order to pin the Fermi level in the conduction band instead of its usual position in the bandgap. In a sense this gives me some insight into my question; for the InSb wires used in the experiments referenced above measurements of bare (no Al shell) wires show that they are not doped, and that the Fermi level is in the gap like in GaAs. However, after contacting it with Al they do see superconductivity; to me this can be seen as that the Al therefore has effectively doped the surface of the InSb, which I personally can only understand through the formation of an accumulation layer. So I'd take this as an indication that indeed, for undoped systems one would need such an accumulation layer. However, you can also strongly dope it to help overcome depletion, as shown in this paper. I don't know this to be true for sure though, so I'll keep the question open for someone who has actual know-how.